# Remove middle characters (milliseconds) excel

Tags: excel

I have my date format this way "24-DEC-15 05:08:32:837000 PM"
I tried changing the date / time format cell but nothing happens
Is there a way I can truncate the milliseconds(:837000) without doing text to columns. I have over 1000 rows this way so manual solution may not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [Substitute Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUBSTITUTE-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332):

```
=--SUBSTITUTE(A1,":",".",3)
```

Which would substitute the third `:` with `.`.  The problem is not that the milliseconds are there, it is that in Excel the separator is `.` not `:`.  By changing it to a `.` it can be read by Excel as a valid date/time.

The `--` forces what is stored as Text to be a number.  Then you can format the cell anyway you want.

Or you can force the format with the TEXT() function:

```
=TEXT(--SUBSTITUTE(A1,":",".",3),"d-mmm-yy hh:mm:ss.000 AM/PM")
```

Comment: Thanks!! Worked perfectly!

Comment: @KiranKrishan please consider marking as correct . click on green check mark by answer